# Prove function is measurable

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory

I was watching this exercise

> Let $\{a_{ij}\}\subseteq [0,+\infty]$ be a sequence. Prove that 
>   $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_{ij} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{ij}$$

If we define $f_n(i) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^n a_{ij}$. Is easy to see that is a monotone sequence and the idea is use the monotone convergence theorem, but I have problems to prove that $f_n$ is measurable with the counting measure defined as $\mu: {\cal P}(\mathbb{N})\rightarrow[0,+\infty]$.

Actually I have problems to prove if a function is measurable in general, some advise or paper to learn?

Comment: For the counting measure, _every_ function is measurable.

Comment: Related questions: [Positivity and Interchange of Summation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89814/positivity-and-interchange-of-summation),
[Under what condition we can interchange order of a limit and a summation?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23057/under-what-condition-we-can-interchange-order-of-a-limit-and-a-summation)
and [When can you switch the order of limits?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15240/when-can-you-switch-the-order-of-limits/)

Answer (score 2):

A function $f:X\to [0,\infty]$ is measurable iff $f^{-1}(V)$ is measurable for any open set $V \subset [0,\infty]$. In this case, $f^{-1}(V) \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, so it is measurable.