# "Commutativity" of sums

Tags: summation

In general, is $\sum_i \sum_j f(i,j) = \sum_j\sum_i f(i,j)$ ?

With $f(i,j)$ I mean some expression that depends on $i$ and $j$.

If yes, how could I prove that?

Comment: This holds for FINITE sums. As for the proof: isn't it obvious? Addition is commutative.

Comment: @Crostul sure. What are the infinite cases?

Comment: Maybe the OP should be more specific, since its summations are dependent on some unspecified set of indices.

Comment: @SimonS Infinite cases are those that add up to infinity; these series are typically found in taylor series and such

Comment: By infinite cases I mean when the index sets for $i$ and $j$ are (countably) infinite. What's interesting then is when the sums do commute. I'm hesitating in giving an answer because I think I know a very strong sufficient condition, but I'd rather have someone chime in who works with these sorts of expressions more than I do.

Comment: If I recall correctly, this is a [special case of Tonelli's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions) and is valid iff $f(i,j)$ is non-negative $\forall~i,j$.

Comment: I (OP) do want to include infinite cases

Comment: That's the very strong sufficient condition I was thinking of. The "only if" direction of that implication is false, e.g., if there are finitely many negative terms. Now, what if there are infinitely many negative terms?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Positivity and Interchange of Summation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89814/positivity-and-interchange-of-summation)

Answer (score 7):

$$\sum_i\sum_jf(i,j) = \sum_i( f(i,j_1) + f(i,j_2)+...+f(i,j_n)) =$$$$ \sum_i f(i,j_1)+\sum_if(i,j_2)+...+\sum_i f(i,j_n)=$$
$$[f(i_1,j_1)+f(i_1,j_2)+...+f(i_1,j_n)]+[f(i_2,j_1)+f(i_2,j_2)+...+f(i_2,j_n)]+...+[f(i_m,j_1)+f(i_m,j_2)+...+f(i_m,j_n)] =$$
$$ [f(i_1,j_1)+f(i_2,j_1)+...+f(i_m,j_1)]+[f(i_1,j_2)+f(i_2,j_2)+...+f(i_m,j_2)]+...+[f(i_1,j_n)+f(i_2,j_n)+...+f(i_m,j_n)] =$$
$$
\sum_j f(i_1,j)+\sum_j f(i_2,j)+...+\sum_j f(i_m,j) = \sum_j\sum_if(i,j).\square$$

Comment: As discussed in the comments above, this finite case is trivial.

Comment: I guess there is a misprint in the derivation above in the line "3" where you expanded in "j" not in "i".