# Iterated series of a particular form

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{x_{i,j}:i\ge1,j\ge1\}$ be real numbers. In general,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty x_{i,j}\ne\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_{i,j}.
$$
If $x_{i,j}\ge0$ for $i\ge1$ and $j\ge1$ or either of the iterated series converges absolutely, then both of the iterated series are equal (see, for example, [Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89814/positivity-and-interchange-of-summation)).

I'm interested in an iterated series of a particular form.

> Suppose that $x_{i,j}=a_{i,j}b_j$, where $\{a_{i,j}:i\ge1,j\ge1\}$ and $\{b_j:j\ge1\}$ are real numbers and $a_{i,j}\ge0$ for $i\ge1$ and $j\ge1$. Are the iterated series
>   $$
> \sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{i,j}b_j\quad\text{and}\quad\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{i,j}b_j
> $$
>   equal if we know that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{i,j}<\infty$ for $j\ge1$, $\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{i,j}=\infty$, but the series $\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{i,j}b_j$ converges (it does not converge absolutely)?

Since $\{b_j:j\ge1\}$ are not necessarily non-negative and the latter iterated series does not converge absolutely, I cannot use Tonelli's theorem. So I'm interested in any results that can be used when Tonelli's theorem is not applicable. Also, I was trying to find a counterexample, but I didn't manage to find one.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are there no conditions on $b_j$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor We only know that the series $\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{i,j}b_j$ converges.

Comment: But then I recall seeing a counterexample somewhere for $b_j=1$...

Comment: @CalvinKhor If $b_j=1$, then both iterated series are equal since $a_{i,j}\ge0$ for $i\ge1$ and $j\ge1$.

Comment: Oh right! haha sorry :)

Comment: Well, the counterexample still works :P We just move the sign into $b_j$, i.e. $x_{ij} = \Bbb 1_{i=j} + \Bbb 1_{i=j+1}$, and $b_j = (-1)^j$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yeah, I should adjust my question. I'm interested in the case when $\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{i,j}=\infty$, but the series $\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{i,j}b_j$ converges. Otherwise it doesn't make much sense. Does your counterexample also work in this case?

Comment: I have a new counterexample! Take $b_j=(-1)^{j+1}$, $a_{ij}$ to be
$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ &\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\ && &\ddots \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: i.e. $a_{ij} = \frac{1}{j}[ \Bbb 1_{i=j} + \Bbb 1_{i=j+1}]+\Bbb 1_{i=j=1}$ We do in fact have $∑∑a_{ij} = ∞$. Taking the horizontal($=i$) sum first, then multiplying every other row by $-1$, the answer is $2\gamma$. But if you multiply every other row by -1 and take a vertical($=j$) sum first, you end up with $$\frac{3}{2} + \sum_{n=2}^∞ \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n(n+1)} = -\log 4 $$. (Thanks, W|A : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28-1%29%5En%2F%28n%28n%2B1%29%29%20from%20n%3D2%20to%20infinity )

Comment: No, I messed up. I'll try again

Answer (score 1):

So from the comments, we are trying to find a counterexample to

$$\begin{cases}a_{i,j}\geq 0 \\b_j ∈ℝ \\\sum^∞_{j=1}\sum^∞_{i=1}a_{i,j}=∞ \\  \sum^∞_{j=1}\sum^∞_{i=1}|a_{i,j}b_j|=∞\\
\sum^∞_{j=1}\sum^∞_{i=1}a_{i,j}b_j<∞\\ \end{cases} \overset{?}{\implies} \sum^∞_{j=1}\sum^∞_{i=1}a_{i,j}b_j = \sum_{i=1}^∞ \sum_{j=1}^∞ a_{i,j}b_j$$

i.e. is this enough to exchange the order of summation?
One can check that my first try from the comments,
$$a = {\tiny \begin{pmatrix}2   \\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{3}\\ 
&&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4}\\ 
&&&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{5}\\ 
&&&&\ddots&
\end{pmatrix}},\quad b_j = (-1)^{j+1}$$
(omitted entries are $0$) satisfies the assumptions but both sums are $\log(4)$.

After much trial and error I have a counterexample :)

Let $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$,$b_n = (-1)^{n+1}$. It is known that $∑x_nb_n$ converges conditionally to $\log 2$, and we can also find some bijection $\sigma:\Bbb N→\Bbb N$ such that $\sum x_{\sigma(n)}b_{\sigma(n)}$ is any value you want  $\xi\inℝ ∪ \{± ∞\}$. We will do a similar thing to force a different value when you switch the order of summation. The idea is that (for $n>1$) we will have the $n$th row sum to $x_nb_n$, so that the sum of row sums gives $\log 2$, but each sum along a column can be controlled.

Fix a $\xi∈\Bbb R$.
Start with $b_j = (-1)^{j+1}$, and $a$ the infinite matrix of $0$s and a single $x_1=1$,

$$a=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & & &\\
& & &\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Once we give a value to $a_{i_0,j_0}$, we will choose to ensure that the values above and under it are $0$ i.e. $\{a_{i_0,j_0± k} : k∈\Bbb N\} = \{0\}$. Thus before we finish defining $a$, we can talk of the partial sum of **column** sums, $$S_N := \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^∞ a_{ij}b_j$$

To decide which value to include next, check if $S_N>\xi$ or $X_N\leq \xi$. If $S_N>\xi$, then we want to include some negative values in the next column, i.e. we will populate the next columns with entries in *even* rows,

$$a=\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
 &x_2 \\
 &0\\
 &&\ddots\\
&&&0\\
&&&x_{N_1}\\
\\
&&&&&
\end{pmatrix}$$
And we keep going until $S_{N_1}\leq\xi$. (This happens eventually as $\sum x_{2n} =∞) $. At this point, we return to the odd rows we have yet to fill in, and start filling in values in the next columns,

$$a=\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
 &x_2 \\
 &0 &&&x_3\\
 &&\ddots&&&\ddots\\
&&&0&&&&x_{N_2}\\
&&&x_{N_1}\\
\\
&&&&&
\end{pmatrix}$$

until $S_{N_2} < \xi$.

In this way, we will fill every row with exactly one number $x_n$. Thus the row sum $\sum_ia_{ij}b_j = b_j x_j$, and so $$\sum_j\sum_ia_{ij}b_j = \sum_j b_j x_j = \log 2$$

However, by construction, the partial sum of column sums tends to $\xi$,
$$S_N = \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^∞ a_{ij}b_j\xrightarrow[N→∞]{}\xi$$ (There is an simple modification for $\xi=±∞$.)