# When can I define a global measure since "partial" measures?

Tags: measure-theory

I have a little question about measure theory.

Suposse that I have a measurable space $(X,\mathcal{M})$. Moreover, suppose that there exists a partition of $X$ in subsets $\{X_n\}_{n\in \omega}$ and finite measures $\mu_n$ over $X_n$ . To me is natural to define  a "measure" over $X$ by $\mu:=\sum_{n\in \omega}\mu_n$ but I have doubts about if this really define a positive measure over $X$. My problem appears with the $\sigma$-aditivity. More precisely, if $\{A_k\}_{k\in\omega}$  is a sequence of disjoint sets on $\mathcal{M}$  I ever can ensure that 
$$
\sum_{n\in\omega}\sum_{k\in\omega}\mu_n(A_k\cap X_n)=\sum_{k\in\omega}\sum_{n\in\omega}\mu_n(A_k\cap X_n)
$$
i,e, under which conditions can I change the order of the sum?

Comment: Those are non-negative terms, no other conditions are needed.

Comment: @logarithm So, in general if I have a double sum of positive terms can I ever change your order?

Comment: Yes, the sum is the supremum of all finite sub-sums no matter the order.

Answer (score 1):

[Positivity and Interchange of Summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89814/positivity-and-interchange-of-summation) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem

**The result.** If $a_{nk}\ge 0$ is increasing in $n$, then $\lim_n \sum_k a_{nk} = \sum_k \lim_n  a_{nk}$ (even if infinite)

**Proof.** Of course, $\sum_k a_{nk} \le \sum_k \lim_n  a_{nk}$, which provides one inequality. But the other inequality is provided by Fatou's lemma,
$$ \sum_k\liminf_n a_{nk} \le\liminf_n\sum_ka_{nk}$$
since in both cases $\liminf = \lim$.

By setting $a_{nk} = \sum_{m =0}^n b_{mk}$ and then reversing the order of summation, we get the equality in the question.