# Showing $ C \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}=C \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=j+1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, statistics

I have the following nested sum that is mentioned in a statistic textbook without any justification. The transformation really doesnt seem obvious to me. Could someone maybe elaborate how this holds?

$$ C \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}=C \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=j+1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}$$

Comment: The summands are non-negative numbers, you can carry the sum in any order your want. On both sides, the index runs over same set of $(j,k) \in \mathbb{Z}^{2}$. Namely, those with $j < k$. As a result, the sum evaluates to same value.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89814/positivity-and-interchange-of-summation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if $j \le k-1$, then we have $k \ge j+1$:

\begin{align}
\{(k, j) \in \mathbb{Z}^2: 2 \le k, 1 \le j \le k-1\} = \{(k, j) \in \mathbb{Z}^2:  1 \le j ,  j+1 \le k   \}
\end{align}

More details:

- If $2 \le k , 1 \le j \le k-1$, then we have $1 \le j$ and $(j \le k-1 \iff k \ge j+1)$.
- If $1 \le j $ and $k \ge j+1$, then clearly we have $k \ge j+1 \ge 1+1=2$ and $1 \le j$ and $(k \ge j+1 \iff j \le k-1)$.

Try to learn to sketch the region and describe the region in two different orders. Also note that all the terms are nonnegative.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a two dimensional plot $(k,j)$ and start to put dots where the sum is evaluated.  You'll see that if you go in one direction, say fix $k$ and bound $j$ by $1..k-1$.  But if you "rotate" your point of view, and fix $j$, you see that $j$ goes from 1 to $\infty$ but $k$ starts at the point $j+1$ and goes to $\infty$.

Comment: The important point is that all numbers are non-negative (or that the double series converges absolutely). Otherwise changing the order of summation might very well change the sum.