# Interchanging order of limits

Tags: limits, poisson-distribution

How do we reconcile the following difference? Specifically, what prevents us from changing the order of limits here?

$$\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda} \lambda^n/n! = \lim_{\lambda \to \infty}1 = 1$$
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^N e^{-\lambda} \lambda^n/n! = \lim_{N \to \infty}0 = 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial dose not converges to $e^{\lambda}$ uniformly on the whole real line, so you cannot carelessly interchanging the limit and summation.

For a thorough discussion, see [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23057/under-what-condition-we-can-interchange-order-of-a-limit-and-a-summation) or any general textbook on analysis.