# limit of infinite sum equal infinite sum of limits?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits

I just asked a similar looking question, but this one is a different question. 
Suppose that
$$\lim_{u \to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x_i(u)=L$$
where $x_i$ is a function of $u$. Then does it follow that
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\lim_{u \to \infty}x_i(u)=L$$
whenever $\lim_{u \to \infty}x_i(u)$ exists for every $i$? If not, then what sufficient conditions would guarantee this equality?

Comment: It does not follow in general.  But there are certain s ufficient conditions for which the interchange is legitimate.

Comment: If you search this site a bit, you will probably find several questions which are rather similar. For example, [Under what condition we can interchange order of a limit and a summation?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23057/under-what-condition-we-can-interchange-order-of-a-limit-and-a-summation) and maybe also [some other posts linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/23057). Checking the list of related question which is in the sidebar on the right might be a reasonable thing to do, too. (This is list generated by Stack Exchange software based on your question.)

Comment: The usual sufficient condition for $\lim_{a \to 0} \lim_{b \to 0} f(a,b) =\lim_{b \to 0} \lim_{a \to 0}  f(a,b)$ is that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$. Here $f(a,b) = \sum_{i =0}^{\lfloor 1/b\rfloor} x_i(1/a)$