# When we can exchange the limits?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\{a_{i,k}\}$ a enumerable family of non-negatives real numbers, suppose that for all $i$, $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty} a_{k,i}$ exist. There are conditions for $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} a_{k,i} = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty} a_{k,i}$ holds?

Comment: I think you question is already answered in [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23057/under-what-condition-we-can-interchange-order-of-a-limit-and-a-summation)

Comment: This is related to Monotone and Dominated Convergence Theorem, and summation can be generalised to integrals of arbitrary measures.