# The limit of a real sum

Tags: calculus, limits

**Do you have a reference to the following problem?

Show that

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(1-\frac in\right)^n = \frac{1}{e-1}.
$$

This problem is solved (I believe incorrectly) in

```
     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nPNB26hxLPc&t=607s
```

by using:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^na_{i,n}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{i,n}
$$

where $a_{i,n}$ is real.

This interchange of limit and sum is true in the given problem where $a_{i,n} = \left(1- \frac in\right)^n$but false when $a_{i,n} = \frac 1n$ .

Comment: Perhaps related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164074/how-to-evaluate-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sum-limits-k-1n-fracknn?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question (after the first few answers) to match the problem in the referenced website.

Comment: Of course, it should be 1/(e-1). Sorry.

Comment: To break down the example I think you are trying to give:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac in=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^ni=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{2}\to\infty$$
As a comparison,
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{i}{n}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty 0=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyze when this exchange of sum and limit is allowed. It can be written  as $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n a_{i,n} = \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^m \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_{i,n}$$
We can freely add $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}$ in the first term and in the second term we can put $\sum_{i=1}^m$ under $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$, to get the condition
$$ \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n a_{i,n} =  \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^m a_{i,n} $$
assuming these limits are finite, we can write this condition as
$$ \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \big(\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i,n} - \sum_{i=1}^m a_{i,n}\big) =  0 $$

> $$ \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=m+1}^n a_{i,n} =   0$$

As you've noticed, it's not always satisfied; for $a_{i,n} =\frac1 n$ we have $$ \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=m+1}^n \frac{1}{n} = \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n-m}{n} = \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} 1 = 1 \neq 0$$
However, if, for example, we can find a bound $|a_{i,n}| \le M_i$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty M_i $ is a convergent series, then this condition is satisfied, because $$ 0 \le \left| \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=m+1}^n a_{i,n}\right| \le \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  \sum_{i=m+1}^n M_i = \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=m+1}^\infty M_i = 0$$ 
In the problem from the video this condition is satisfied, because $$ a_{i,n} =(1-\frac{i}{ n})^n \le e^{-i} =: M_i$$

In conclusion a criterion that allows to get with the limit under the sum in this case is

> If there exists a sequence $M_i$ such that for every $n\in\mathbb N$ we have $|a_{i,n}| \le M_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty M_i$ is convergent, then $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n a_{i,n} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_{i,n}$$

I believe this to be a special case of [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test). $a_{i,n}=\frac1 n$ obviously doesn't satisfy this criterion. There may exist weaker criteria, but this one is sufficient.

Comment: I don't quite understand the first part of this, but you are basically using a form of the dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to start:
$$S=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(1-\frac in\right)^n=\sum_{i=1}^\infty e^{-i}$$
this is because:
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{k}\right)^k=e^x$$
now all we have left is a geometric series, which we know has the formula:
$$S=a\frac{1}{1-r}=\frac{1/e}{1-1/e}=\frac{1}{e-1}$$

Comment: You're interchanging limit and sum which I showed by the example in my question isn't always correct. It does work in this example but needs justification.

Comment: you can find a similar question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23057/under-what-condition-we-can-interchange-order-of-a-limit-and-a-summation

Comment: I presume it to be true in this case because each term is positive and through the converge test the series is convergent, and the limit of the kth term $\to 0$

Comment: My counterexample satisfies all your criteria but is still gives an incorrect result.

Comment: Your counter arguement is not a convergent series

Comment: Lim(as n approaches inf)[Sum(i = 1 to n){i/n}] = Lim(n approarches inf)[1] =1  .            Sum (i = 1 to inf)[Lim (n approaches inf) {1/n} = Sum(i = 1 to inf)[0] =0  .

Comment: In your question it says 1/n

Comment: You have not justified why you can interchange the limit and sum.  You need to refer to a theorem that allows you to do this.

Comment: I literally linked a question detailing the same thing you are asking

Comment: @HenryLee Please add that explicit justification to your answer and don't just quote the other answer. State the property which is satisfied. It is easy to overlook comments like this.