# Prove $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^{\frac{-kn}{k+n}}=2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, alternative-proof

I'm asked to prove 
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^{\frac{-kn}{k+n}}=2$$

Define $$b_{k,n} = \begin{cases}
0,& n \le k\\
2^{\frac{-kn}{k+n}},& n \ge k\\
\end{cases}$$

Our limit is equivalent to finding $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_{k,n}$. It's appealing to write

$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_{k,n}=^?\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\lim_{n\to \infty} b_{k,n}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^{-k}=2$$

Question 1:

> Can we justify the swapping of sum and limit here? (*solved*)

Question 2:

> Is there any alternative approach?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23057/under-what-condition-we-can-interchange-order-of-a-limit-and-a-summation

Comment: @Klangen Noted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The series can be dominated by $$ b_{k,n} \le 2^{-\frac{k}{2}}$$
For $n < k$ this is obivously true, as we have $b_{k,n} = 0$. For $n\ge k$ we have
$$ n \ge  k$$
$$ \frac1n \le \frac 1k$$
$$ \frac1k + \frac1n \le \frac2k$$ 
$$ \frac{kn}{k+n} = \frac{1}{\frac1k + \frac1n} \ge \frac{k}{2}$$
$$ b_{k,n} = 2^{-\frac{kn}{k+n}} \le 2^{-\frac{k}{2}}$$
Series $ \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-\frac{k}{2}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(\sqrt{2})^k}$ is convergent, so from the dominated convergence theorem, you can justify the swapping of the sum and the limit.

More fundamental proof:
Let us decompose $$ \sum_{k=0}^n 2^{-\frac{kn}{k+n}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor} 2^{-\frac{kn}{k+n}} + \sum_{k={\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor+1}}^n 2^{-\frac{kn}{k+n}}$$

For $k \in [\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor + 1,n] $ we have $$ \frac{kn}{k+n} > \frac{\sqrt{n} n}{n+ n}= \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}$$ $$ 2^{-\frac{kn}{k+n}} < 2^{-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}}$$
We have then $$ \sum_{k={\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor+1}}^n 2^{-\frac{kn}{k+n}} < (n-\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor) 2^{-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}} < n2^{-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}} \rightarrow 0$$
so
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k={\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor+1}}^n 2^{-\frac{kn}{k+n}} = 0$$

For $k \in [0,\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor]$  we have $$ \frac{kn}{\sqrt{n}+n}\le \frac{kn}{k+n} \le k $$
$$ 2^{-k} \le 2^{-\frac{kn}{k+n}} \le 2^{-\frac{kn}{\sqrt{n}+n}} $$ 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor} 2^{-k} \le \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor} 2^{-\frac{kn}{k+n}} \le \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor} 2^{-\frac{kn}{\sqrt{n}+n}} $$
$$ \frac{1-2^{-\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor-1}}{1-2^{-1}} \le \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor} 2^{-\frac{kn}{k+n}} \le \frac{1-2^{-\frac{(\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor+1)n}{\sqrt{n}+n}}}{1-2^{-\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}+n}}} $$
We have $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1-2^{-\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor-1}}{1-2^{-1}}  = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1-2^{-\frac{(\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor+1)n}{\sqrt{n}+n}}}{1-2^{-\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}+n}}}  = 2  $$
which means that also $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor} 2^{-\frac{kn}{k+n}} = 2 $$

Altogether we have $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n 2^{-\frac{kn}{k+n}}  = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \Big(\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor} 2^{-\frac{kn}{k+n}} + \sum_{k={\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor+1}}^n 2^{-\frac{kn}{k+n}}\Big) = 2 + 0 =2$$

Comment: Thanks for your assistance! (+1) Do you know of a more elementary proof? (without invoking the dominance convergence theorem; as I'm not supposed to use it)

Comment: @YuiToCheng  I've added the more fundamental proof.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, I'vec licked to fast by mistake; I've finished it now.

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out.

Comment: Nicely done. The 'split' technique is really useful.