# Two almost geometric series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The following problems appears in *Makarov, B. M. , et al, Selected Problems in Real Analysis, Translation of Mathematica Monographs, AMS, 1992*.

> Define the sequences
>
> 1. $x_n=\sum^{2n}_{k=0}2^{-k}\cos(\sqrt{k/n})$
> 2. $y_n=\sum^{2n}_{k=0}2^{-\tfrac{nk}{n+k}}$
>
> Determine the limits of $x_n$ and $y_n$.

Armed with the tools of integration theory (dominated convergence), it is possible to solve this problems rather easily. For example, in (1) we may consider the finite measure space $(\mathbb{Z}_+,\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}_+),\mu)$ where
$$\mu=\sum^\infty_{k=0}2^{-k}\delta_k$$
The sequence $f_n(x)=\cos(\sqrt{x/n})\mathbb{1}_{\{0,\ldots,2n\}}(x)$ satisfies $|f_n|\leq 1$ and $\lim_nf_n=\cos(0)$. Hence
$$x_n=\sum^{2n}_{k=0}2^{-k}\cos(\sqrt{k/n})=\int f_n\,d\mu\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}2$$

**Question:** The set of problems containing the exercise  above seemed to be for students with good Calculus knowledge (sequences, differentiation and Riemann integration). My question is whether someone present a solution, albeit no necessarily easier,  using the tools of College Calculus to either of these two exercises.

***Edit*** An elementary solution to the the limit in (2)- elementary in the sense that only basic methods from Calculus- is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3275998/121671).

Comment: Do you allow Riemann sums?

Comment: @StefanLafon: It could be, anything within the typical College Calculus syllabus. I though about Riemann sums for a while but  did not see a clear path.

Comment: College calculus student here: how is it that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=\cos(1)$, when $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos(\sqrt{x/n})=\cos(0)=1$ since $\sqrt{x}$ and $\cos$ are continuous, the limit can be passed all the way inside...

Comment: From my very short education on Lebesgue theory, I gather that your indicator function (I assume that’s what $\Bbb{1}$ is) is an indicator for the integers $\{0,1,\ldots,2n\}$ which means $f_n$ is only non-zero for integer $x$ - is this correct?

Comment: @FShrike: correct. I prefer the probabilist notation for the *indicator* function of a set.

Comment: @JeanL. You can consider the counting measure $\nu=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\delta_k$. $g_n(x)=2^{-\tfrac{x}{1+\tfrac{x}{n}}}\mathbb{1}_{\{0,\ldots,2n\}}(x)$. Now $|g_n(x)|\leq (\sqrt[3]{2})^{-x}=g(x)$ and $\int g\,d\nu <\infty$. Notice $\lim_ng_n(x)=2^{-x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_n:=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}2^{-k}$.

$$
|x_n-a_n|\le \sum_{k=0}^{2n}2^{-k}|\cos(\sqrt{k/n})-1| \le \sum_{k=0}^{2n}2^{-k}\sqrt{k/n}
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}2^{-k}\sqrt{k} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{-k}\sqrt{k} \to 0 ~ (n \to \infty).
$$
As $a_n \to 2$ also $x_n \to 2$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks Gerd. That was rather simple. The second limit is probably a little harder.

Comment: I think the second limit is a bit more technical, but the same idea should work by using Lipschitz continuity of $x \mapsto 2^x$ on bounded sets.