# Interchange of $\lim$ and $\sum$ for $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}}e^{-n^2 x}e^{ix}.$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

Define $f:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb C$ by $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}}e^{-n^2 x}e^{ix}$. (This is convergent uniformly from M-test.)

I want to show $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$.

Since $e^{-n^2 x}e^{ix}\to 0 $ as $x\to \infty$ for $n\in \mathbb Z\setminus \{0\}$, it suffices to justify the interchange of $\lim$ and $\sum.$

But what justifies the interchange ?

Is the uniformity of convergence enough to say $\lim \sum =\sum \lim$ ? I don't know the sufficient condition for changing limit and summation.

This post [Under what condition we can interchange order of a limit and a summation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23057/under-what-condition-we-can-interchange-order-of-a-limit-and-a-summation) is similar to my question but in my case, the limit is $x\to \infty$, $x$ doesn't necessarily in $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don’t have to investigate the problem of changing the order of limit and summation in this problem. Here is a more direct way: since $n^2x>nx$ for $n\geq1$ and $x>0$, we have
$$|f(x)|\leq 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2x}\leq 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nx}=2\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}.$$
Now it is obvious that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$.

**Change the order of limit and summation.** The problem of changing the order of limit and summation is usually converted to the problem of changing the order of limit and integration:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty F(n,x)=\int_{\mathbb N_{\geq 1}}F(n,x)\,d\mu(n),$$
where $\mu$ is [the counting measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure) on $\mathbb N_{\geq 1}$. By [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem), if $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(n,x)=G(n)$ for all $n$, and
$$|F(n,x)|\leq g(n),\qquad \text{for all }\  n\geq 1, x\ \  \text{large},$$
for some $g$ with $\int_{\mathbb N_{\geq 1}}g(n)\,d\mu(n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty g(n)<\infty$, then we have
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb N_{\geq 1}}F(n,x)\,d\mu(n)=\int_{\mathbb N_{\geq 1}}G(n)\,d\mu(n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty G(n).$$

**Apply to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2x}e^{ix}$:** We have $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-n^2x}e^{ix}=0$ for all $n\geq 1$, and
$$|e^{-n^2x}e^{ix}|\leq e^{-n^2},\qquad \forall n\geq 1,x\geq1,$$
and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2}<\infty$. Therefore, the second paragraph implies that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2x}e^{ix}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-n^2x}e^{ix}=0.$$

*Remark.* Dominated convergence theorem (DCT) is a very powerful theorem dealing with the problem of changing the order of limit and integration (we have seen that summation is a special case of integration). You will learn this theorem in Real Analysis course (According to the questions you have asked in this site, I think you haven't learnt that course.)

Answer (score 1):

$|\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}}e^{-n^2 x}e^{ix}|\leq \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}}e^{-n^2 x}\leq \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}}e^{-|n|x}=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-nx}$. Sum this geometric series and let $x \to \infty$.

[ If you want a justification without writing out the sum let $t=\frac 1  e$. Then $e^{-nx} \leq t^{n}$ for $x >1$ The series $\sum t^{n}$ is convergent. So DCT is applicable].